# Pandas - Increase date by 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this,

```
ID    DateCol
1      26/06/2017
2      Employee Not Found
```

I want to increase the date by 1.

The expected output is,

```
ID    DateCol
1      27/06/2017
2      Employee Not Found
```

I tried,

```
temp_result_df['NewDateCol'] = pd.to_datetime(temp_result_df['DateCol']).apply(pd.DateOffset(1))
```

And it is not working, as I believe there is a string on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is best working with `datetimes` in column with `NaT` for missing values - use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `Timedelta` or `Day` offset:

```
temp_result_df['NewDateCol'] = pd.to_datetime(temp_result_df['DateCol'], errors='coerce') 

temp_result_df['NewDateCol'] += pd.Timedelta(1, 'd')
#alternative
#temp_result_df['NewDateCol'] += pd.offsets.Day(1)
print (temp_result_df)
   ID             DateCol NewDateCol
0   1          26/06/2017 2017-06-27
1   2  Employee Not Found        NaT
```

If need strings like original data need [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with `replace`:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(temp_result_df['DateCol'], errors='coerce') + pd.Timedelta(1, 'd')

temp_result_df['NewDateCol'] = s.dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y').replace('NaT','Employee Not Found')
print (temp_result_df)
   ID             DateCol          NewDateCol
0   1          26/06/2017          27/06/2017
1   2  Employee Not Found  Employee Not Found
```